# i need a circuit to kiss NO contacts no matter how long you hold the button

Tags: relay

I am working on a license camera at a gated community and the nvr is holding the gate up to long. the lowest setting is 5s but I need it to be 1 sec. I looking for a made relay or a circuit to build that will just kiss the contact even if the momentary is held for 5 seconds but then reset and trigger again when pressed again.

Comment: "***kiss** the contact*"? "*nvr*"? IMHO those terms need explaining, as well as a more step-by-step description of the behaviour you *have* and the behaviour you *want* would also help, including details (ideally a diagram) of the original circuit if possible, and places (ideally marked on that diagram) where you can attach whatever circuit you design. Please edit the question to include them.

Comment: Having a gate that automatically drops after a second even while the button is still held sounds like a truly terrible idea.

Comment: That is a non-retriggerable one-shot.  Can be made with  a 555 chip.

Comment: ok so the gate has its own timer circuit as well as a magnetic reader for when the car passes. the guard has a simple momentary button which I have paralleled off to the Network Video Recorder. the NVR is holding the circuit to long. It Should be a short burst or kiss. not a 5 second hold. so now I am getting cars piggy backing each other and going thru the gate before authorization.

Comment: So the use of the Camera is for Residence who live in the community license plate's be registered on the network video recorder's (white list) and will auto open the gate. This feature I have working perfectly. The only issue is the Nvr holding the pulse for 5 seconds. I need to take that pulse and drop it to 1 second and then reset after 5 seconds to start again

Comment: We call this a passive One Shot. Do you need block trigger for 5 seconds too?

Comment: Define all input/output voltage, polarity, and time duration tolerances and non-retrigger hold times if needed to improve quality of question.  (Which is why the "Mods" put it on hold)  FYI I used negative logic Vdd voltage eg 5 or 3.3) switch. You can use +ve logic switch to do similar

Comment: I am no longer on site but it is either 12 or 24 volt dc. Time duration would be 1 second. Non-Retriggering would be about 8s to give the network recorder time to clear and then get ready for next car. but having that adjustable for real life situation would be helpful

Answer (score 2):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f85E1x.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[Falstad browser Simulation](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%2012%200.001555%2018.278915558614752%2050%205%2043%0Ad%20320%20208%20320%20160%202%20default%0Ad%20320%20256%20320%20208%202%20default%0Ad%20288%20256%20288%20208%202%20default%0Ad%20288%20208%20288%20160%202%20default%0Ar%20288%20208%20320%20208%200%2010000%0AI%20320%20208%20400%20208%200%200.5%205%0AR%20288%20160%20288%20128%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Ag%20288%20256%20288%20288%200%0Aw%20320%20256%20288%20256%200%0Aw%20320%20160%20288%20160%200%0Aw%20288%20208%20240%20208%202%0Ar%20240%20160%20240%20208%200%201200000%0Ar%20128%20160%20128%20208%200%20100000%0Ar%20192%20208%20128%20208%200%20100%0Ac%2032%20160%2032%20208%202%200.000001%20-1.074695887836512e-13%0Aw%20288%20160%20240%20160%200%0Aw%20240%20160%20128%20160%200%0Aw%20128%20208%20128%20224%200%0Aw%20288%20256%20128%20256%200%0As%20128%20256%20128%20224%200%201%20true%0Aw%20400%20208%20432%20208%200%0Aw%20128%20208%2064%20208%200%0A209%20240%20208%20192%20208%200%200.000001%20-0.08277805696478602%2010%0A403%20352%20240%20480%20304%200%2022_64_0_4354_0.15625_0.0001953125_0_2_22_3%0A403%20352%20128%20480%20192%200%203_64_0_4097_0.15625_0.00009765625_0_2_3_3%0Aw%20128%20160%2064%20160%200%0Ao%2021%2064%200%204354%2010%200.00009765625%200%202%2021%203%0Ao%2010%2064%200%204102%2010%200.00009765625%200%202%2010%203%0Ao%2020%2064%200%204102%205%200.00009765625%200%202%2020%203%0A)

Pull down the resistors if switch goes to V+ instead of 0V.

This reduces the max duration to 1 second

R1C1=1.2 gives  1 second